# How do I add ajax control toolkit to source control?

Tags: version-control, tfs, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Visual Studio 2005
.Net Framework 2.0

I have the AjaxControlToolkit within my web application bin folder along with all the "ar", "de", "fr" etc. folders.

I don't have any of the check-in or check-out icons in these files in the bin but right clicking them allows me to do things like get latest version.

When I access this application on another machine it pulls in everything included the AjaxControlToolkit.dll but nothing else that's in the bin.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dll's and binaries in the bin folder are generated when you build your project/solution based on the solution configuration settings that you can modify in the configuration manager (by right clicking the solution and selecting Configuration Manager).

In order for you to get the check in and check out option on any folder, that folder needs to be added to the source control first. Also, i would recommend that you create an external refs folder in your source control and add the toolkit dll to that folder and add the reference to your web project from this location rather than relying on any other sources (also set the property of the reference to copy local = true), why i say this is because if you have the toolkit framework installed on your local and the dll is available in the gac, the build will not fail, however, it will fail for some one else as they may not have the dll available.

HTH.
Cheers, Tarun